# Unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``' - Bash Script

Tags: bash

Here is my bash script: http://pastebin.com/9kgGYPmt

Ok so simply, when I run the Bash command I get this error: 
http://puu.sh/6oSTW.png

I really don't know why this is happening. Can anyone help? Thanks :)

This script is designed to restart the machine and will eventually be called via a Cron job, but this is unrelated and really only to allow ServerFault to post this question.

Comment: You're going to restart a server via cron job? No, you don't want to do that. If you think you do, you should find and fix the _real_ problem first.

Comment: I am running 20 Minecraft servers. This is two do two things - 1) Allow updates to the servers 2) Refresh resources. This type of thing isn't uncommon in this use case. Java is one memory hog.

Comment: Fine, so kill the java processes, let their memory be reclaimed.  Rebooting the server to restart a process is like shooting someone to cure their cold.

Comment: @MadHatter  Well, maybe he just hates his servers.  I can think of a few people whom I'd recommend shooting as a cure to a cold.  Or a hangnail.  Or a mild itch.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a trivial typo.

You have several lines which include:

```
`echo -ne '\015'\`
```

I presume you mean to embed a <kbd>Ctrl-G</kbd> bell character into the output.

The error is because you have placed an unnecessary backslash before the final backtick, thus escaping it. This isn't what you want.

Remove it:

```
`echo -ne '\015'`
```

---

Another thing: Get rid of this script entirely.

For starters, you really shouldn't be rebooting your server via a cron job. If you think you want to, you have another problem, which you should actually find and fix. Any reasonable server should be able to remain up and running for more than a day without intervention.

Second, the `shutdown` command will happily alert all logged on users (and screen sessions!) automatically. If you really must reboot, try using it to schedule your reboot.